# Order of Inserts

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

For some reason, "End processing." is inserted first into my text box. The process_mp4_file function takes a while to finish.

End processing.

Processed File - /Users/ypm/Desktop/new/three.mp4

Processed File - /Users/ypm/Desktop/new/two.mp4

Processed File - /Users/ypm/Desktop/new/one.mp4

Processed File - /Users/ypm/Desktop/new/testfile.mp4

Starting processing...

```
def process_mp4_file(directory, needle, frames_ps):
    mp4_files = []
    for root, _, files in os.walk(directory):
        for file in files:
            if file.lower().endswith(".mp4"):
                mp4_files.append(os.path.join(root, file))

    for mp4_file in mp4_files:
        df = measureWidths(mp4_file, threshold=100, needle_mm=needle,
                           fps=frames_ps, show=False, skip=2)

        plot = autoRegressor(df)
        plot_directory = os.path.splitext(mp4_file)[0]
        os.makedirs(plot_directory, exist_ok=True)

        csv_filename = os.path.join(plot_directory, 'OriginalData.csv')
        df.to_csv(csv_filename, index=False)

        plot_filename = os.path.join(plot_directory, 'OverlayPlot.png')
        plot.savefig(plot_filename, dpi=200)
        plot.close()
        result_text.insert("1.0", f"Processed File - {mp4_file}\n\n")


def analyze_files():
    fps = int(fps_entry.get())
    needle_w = float(needle_width_entry.get())
    if folder is not None:
        result_text.insert("1.0", f"Starting processing...\n\n")
        process_mp4_file(directory=folder, needle=needle_w, frames_ps=fps)
        result_text.insert("1.0", f"End processing.\n\n")
    else:
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please choose directory!")
    fps_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
    needle_width_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
```

Comment: To ensure that the messages are inserted into the text box in the correct order, you could try calling the process_mp4_file function synchronously, so that it blocks until it has finished executing. Alternatively, if you need to call this function asynchronously, you could use synchronization mechanisms such as locks or semaphores to ensure that the messages are inserted into the text box in the correct order.

Comment: You're explicitly adding things to line 1 every time you call insert, which causes other messages to be pushed down. Try inserting at the end instead.

Comment: Is it not being called synchronously?